# download url from firebase storage comes empty

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, angularfire2, ionic4

I am using ionic 4 to upload the image from camera to the firebase storage. the upload goes fine but i am having hard time in getting the upload URL. my code looks like below:

```
async getFromCamera(){
    this.camera.getPicture({
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      quality: 25,
      correctOrientation: true,
        allowEdit:false
  }).then(async (imageData) => {
      var base64Image = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
      this.uploadToFireStore(base64Image).then(
            (data) => console.log("done to firestore:"  + data),
            (err) => console.log("The error to upload is:::" + JSON.stringify(err))
          )
  }, (err) => {
      console.log("Error found is:" + err);
  });
  }

  uploadPercent
  downloadURL

  uploadToFireStore(imageData){
   return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
    let storageRef = this.storage.ref('/');
    let imageRef = storageRef.child('myimage')
    const task = imageRef.putString(imageData, 'data_url')

      console.log("Task is:::" + task)
       // observe percentage changes
    this.uploadPercent = task.percentageChanges();
    // get notified when the download URL is available
    task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
        finalize(() => {
                            this.downloadURL = imageRef.getDownloadURL() 
                            console.log("upload percent:" + JSON.stringify(this.uploadPercent))
                            console.log("download url is::" + JSON.stringify(this.downloadURL))
                      } 
                )
     )
    .subscribe()
  })
  }
```

The response i see is:

```
upload percent:{"_isScalar":false,"source":{"_isScalar":false},"operator":{}}
/tab1-tab1-module.js:629 download url is::{"_isScalar":false}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase Storage lets you upload files, so you don't need to upload long `base64` strings. Why do you still want to upload `base64`?

I am not familiar with what `this.camera.getPicture` method returns, but pretty sure it is a type of `File`. In that case:

```
}).then(imageData => {
    this.uploadToFireStore(imageData)
```

And

```
  uploadToFireStore(imageData){
    let storageRef = this.storage.ref('/');
    let imageRef = storageRef.child('myimage')
    const task = imageRef.upload(imageData, 'data_url')

    this.uploadPercent = task.percentageChanges();
    task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
        finalize( async () => {
          await this.downloadURL = imageRef.getDownloadURL().toPromise();
          console.log('this.downloadURL', this.downloadURL)

                      } 
                )
     )
    .subscribe()
```

Note that `finalize` takes an `async` function, because `imageRef.getDownloadURL()` returns an Observable, so as we only need one value from it and that is the only value we need of this stream, its looks cleaner to convert it to Promise.

Comment: await this.downloadURL = imageRef.getDownloadURL().toPromise(); i get error saying "; expected"

Comment: Thats a typo error. Check for missing brackets etc. Your provided snippet was very messy, so very likely there are some typos